# Combining points close to one another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, point, spatial-cluster

I need an approach to combine points close one to another into a common point.

I can take an average of points' `{lat, long}` to create one point.

How I can do this with ArcMap or Python? I have an Excel file for those points.

Should I combine according to `{lat, long}` information with Excel?

[image: Example]

Comment: Would this article [Find Point Clusters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/find-point-clusters.htm) be helpful for you? As well as [How Density-based Clustering works](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/how-density-based-clustering-works.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that you are *not* simply trying to set a zoom level on an interactive map, and your point groups near each other do *not* share a common attribute. If my understanding of your question is incorrect, please modify your question to provide more details, as you will get a different answer.

Based on my two assumptions, and piggy-backing off the earlier suggestion to use density-based clustering, here is what I would try using Arcmap (after converting your Excel file into a feature class):

1. Determine the clusters using the [Grouping Analysis tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/grouping-analysis.htm). Use the x and/or y values already present in your dataset, and try different values for the various spatial parameters. This will result in a new feature class with a column that identifies which group each feature belongs to. Symbolize this layer by group number to determine if you are happy with the groupings.
2. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) the points to create multi-part features based on the group number assigned in Step 1.
3. Use [Feature to Point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-point.htm) to obtain the centroid of each multipoint cluster.